# Docker predefined container ip or name inside stack?

Tags: docker

Situation: docker service run under docker swarm via 
`docker stack deploy -c ${compose_file_path} example`. At the same time and at the same stack run another service. The question is: how to interact with first container,  if we cant define container_name (because stack ignoring this option)?
First container runs java app with rest service and second java app has to interact with it. But how can I get it? Thank you in advance.

P.S. I tried to use `docker service create` but there is also troubles with ips.

Comment: Use the name of the service in the compose file (the dictionary key underneath `services:`) as a DNS host name.

Comment: @DavidMaze does it mean that i can access container via servicename:8080 for example